# Unable to call the function UploadDone() after onuploadcompleted is called for Upload File

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Since I am relatively new to software development, I am given the below code to debug as when the user click on Browse on a page, it will popup a new window and after uploading the file, the file will not be auto-populated on the select option in the page and the popup window will not close.

Below are the code in different page. Kindly advise whether there is anything wrong with the code. Thanks.

***Page 1***

```
Public Shared Function NewUploadControl(ByVal ID As String, ByVal FilePath As String, ByRef Parent As Control) As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload
            If Parent.Page Is Nothing Then
                Err.Raise(513, , "Parent control is not added to the Page")
            End If
            Dim ps As New PageScript(Parent.Page, False)
            ps.AddJavaScriptFile(PageScript.VirtualDir & "App_Files/_JavaScript/UIUploadFile.js", "UIUploadFile")

            Dim file As New AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload
            Dim filetable As New HtmlControls.HtmlTable
            Dim img As New Image

            With filetable
                .Width = "100%"
                .CellPadding = 0
                .CellSpacing = 0
                .Rows.Add(New HtmlTableRow)
                .Rows(0).Cells.Add(New HtmlTableCell)
                .Rows(0).Cells.Add(New HtmlTableCell)
                .Rows(0).Cells(0).Controls.Add(img)
                .Rows(0).Cells(1).Controls.Add(file)
            End With

            ''add loading image
            img.ImageUrl = "~/_Images/loading.gif"
            img.ID = "Loading_" & ID
            img.ToolTip = "Uploading File..."

            ''draw file link    
            Dim FileName As String = ""

            file.ID = ID
            If Parent.Page.IsPostBack = False Then
                ResetUploadControl(file)
            End If

            If FilePath <> "" Then
                ''add checkbox
                Dim chk As New CheckBox
                chk.ID = "Remove_" & ID
                chk.AutoPostBack = False
                chk.Text = "Remove"

                Dim linktable As New HtmlControls.HtmlTable
                With linktable
                    .Width = "100%"
                    .CellPadding = 0
                    .CellSpacing = 0
                    .Rows.Add(New HtmlTableRow)
                    .Rows(0).Cells.Add(New HtmlTableCell)
                    .Rows(0).Cells.Add(New HtmlTableCell)
                    .Rows(0).Cells(1).Controls.Add(chk)
                    .Rows(0).Cells(1).Align = "right"
                    .Rows(0).Cells(0).Controls.Add(NewFileLink(FilePath))
                End With
                Parent.Controls.Add(linktable)
            End If

            Parent.Controls.Add(filetable)
            'Change 10-Added .UploaderStyle = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploaderStyle.Traditional
            '.UploaderStyle = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.UploaderStyleEnum.Traditional

            With file
                .ID = ID
                .CssClass = "TextBox"
                .Height = Unit.Pixel(22)
                .Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
                .UploaderStyle = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploaderStyle.Traditional
                .ErrorBackColor = Drawing.Color.Gold
                .UploadingBackColor = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(&H7EBF1F3)
                .CompleteBackColor = Drawing.Color.White
                .OnClientUploadError = "UIForm_UploadError"
                .OnClientUploadComplete = "UIForm_UploadComplete"
                .OnClientUploadStarted = "UIForm_UploadStarted"
                .ThrobberID = img.ID

                AddHandler file.UploadedComplete, AddressOf AsyncFileUpload_UploadedComplete
                AddHandler file.UploadedFileError, AddressOf AsyncFileUpload_UploadedFileError

                .Attributes.Item("Value") = CommonScript.FormatValue(FilePath, GetType(System.String).Name, CommonScript.FormatType.ValueFormat)
                .Attributes.Item("OldValue") = CommonScript.FormatValue(FilePath, GetType(System.String).Name, CommonScript.FormatType.ValueFormat)
            End With
            Return file
        End Function
        
Private Shared Sub AsyncFileUpload_UploadedComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)
            Dim File As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload = sender
            Dim Application As HttpApplicationState = HttpContext.Current.Application
            Dim Session As HttpSessionState = HttpContext.Current.Session
            Dim ErrorMessage As String = ""
            Try
                If (File.HasFile) Then
                    ''check file type
                    Dim ValidFileType As Boolean = False
                    Dim ValidFileHeaderType As Boolean = False


                    If IsValidFileType(File.FileName, File.Attributes("AllowFileType")) Then
                        If IsValidFileType(File.FileName, PageScript.Session("AllowFileType")) Then                            
                            Select Case Path.GetExtension(File.FileName)
                                Case ".png"
                                    If File.ContentType = "image/x-png" Or File.ContentType = "image/x-png" Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    End If
                                Case ".jpeg", ".jpg"
                                    If File.ContentType = "image/jpeg" Or File.ContentType = "image/jpg" Or File.ContentType = "image/pjpeg" Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    End If
                                Case ".bmp"
                                    If File.ContentType = "image/bmp" Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    End If
                                Case ".gif"
                                    If File.ContentType = "image/gif" Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    End If
                                Case ".pdf"
                                    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ConverToBytes(File) 'Change 09
                                    If (fileBytes.Take(7).SequenceEqual(PDF)) = False Then
                                        ValidFileType = False
                                        ValidFileHeaderType = False
                                    Else
                                        If File.ContentType = "application/pdf" Then
                                            ValidFileType = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Case ".doc"
                                    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ConverToBytes(File) 'Change 09
                                    If (fileBytes.Take(8).SequenceEqual(DOC)) = False Then
                                        ValidFileType = False
                                        ValidFileHeaderType = False
                                    Else
                                        If File.ContentType = "application/msword" Then
                                            ValidFileType = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Case ".docx"
                                    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ConverToBytes(File) 'Change 09
                                    If (fileBytes.Take(8).SequenceEqual(DOCX)) = False Then
                                        ValidFileType = False
                                        ValidFileHeaderType = False
                                    Else
                                        If File.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" Then
                                            ValidFileType = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Case ".ppt"
                                    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ConverToBytes(File)
                                    If (fileBytes.Take(8).SequenceEqual(PPT)) = False Then
                                        ValidFileType = False
                                        ValidFileHeaderType = False
                                    Else
                                        If File.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" Then
                                            ValidFileType = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Case ".pptx"
                                    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ConverToBytes(File)
                                    If (fileBytes.Take(8).SequenceEqual(PPTX)) = False Then
                                        ValidFileType = False
                                        ValidFileHeaderType = False
                                    Else
                                        If File.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" Then
                                            ValidFileType = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Case ".xls"
                                    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ConverToBytes(File)
                                    If (fileBytes.Take(8).SequenceEqual(XLS)) = False Then
                                        ValidFileType = False
                                        ValidFileHeaderType = False
                                    Else
                                        If File.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" Then
                                            ValidFileType = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Case ".xlsx"
                                    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = ConverToBytes(File)
                                    If (fileBytes.Take(8).SequenceEqual(XLSX)) = False Then
                                        ValidFileType = False
                                        ValidFileHeaderType = False
                                    Else
                                        If File.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" Then
                                            ValidFileType = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Case ".zip"
                                    If File.ContentType = "application/zip" Or File.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed" Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    End If
                                Case ".txt"
                                    If File.ContentType = "text/plain" Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    End If
                                Case ".csv"
                                    If File.ContentType = "text/csv" Or File.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" Or File.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    End If
                                Case Else
                                    If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DenyFileType") = "" Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    ElseIf IsValidFileType(File.FileName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DenyFileType")) = False Then
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    End If
                                    If IsvalidFileExtensions(File.FileName) = True Then 'Change 09
                                        ValidFileType = True
                                    Else
                                        ValidFileType = False
                                    End If
                            End Select                            
                        End If
                    End If


                    If ValidFileType Then
                        Dim FileExt As String = ""
                        Dim OriginalFileName As String = File.FileName
                        
                        OriginalFileName = SanitizeFileName(OriginalFileName)
                        If InStr(File.FileName, ".") > 0 Then FileExt = Mid(File.FileName, InStr(File.FileName, ".") + 1)
                        
                        Dim TempFileName As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "." & FileExt

                        Dim FilePath As String = FileFunctions.UploadAppTempFolderPath & TempFileName
                        Dim CopyTo As String = FileFunctions.UploadShareFolderPath(Session("CoID"), False) & TempFileName

                        File.SaveAs(FilePath) 'Save File to website > upload temp folder

                        ErrorMessage = FileFunctions.CopyFile(Session("UploadDoc_UserName"), Session("UploadDoc_Domain"), Session("UploadDoc_Password"), FilePath, CopyTo, True, Session("CoID"), OriginalFileName, True)

                        If ErrorMessage = "Successful" Then
                            FilePath = Replace(CopyTo, FileFunctions.UploadShareFolderPath(), "")

                            Session("UploadedFile_" & File.ID) = FilePath
                            Session("UploadedFileName_" & File.ID) = File.FileName
                            PageScript.JavaScript(File.Page, "UIForm_SetUploadError('')")
                            PageScript.JavaScript(File.Page, "UploadDone('" & CommonScript.StrEncode(FilePath, CommonScript.EncodeTypeEnum.JAVAW) & "','" & CommonScript.StrEncode(OriginalFileName, CommonScript.EncodeTypeEnum.JAVAW) & "')")
                        End If                        
                    Else
                        ErrorMessage = "Invalid File Type ! (" & Path.GetExtension(File.FileName) & ") " & File.ContentType
                    End If
                End If
                If ErrorMessage <> "" And ErrorMessage <> "Successful" Then
                    Session("UploadedFile_" & File.ID) = ""
                    Session("UploadedFileName_" & File.ID) = ""
                    PageScript.JavaScript(File.Page, "UIForm_SetUploadError('" & CommonScript.StrEncode(ErrorMessage, CommonScript.EncodeTypeEnum.JAVAW) & "')")
                End If
            Catch er As System.Exception
                PageScript.JavaScript(File.Page, "UIForm_SetUploadError('" & CommonScript.StrEncode(er.Message, CommonScript.EncodeTypeEnum.JAVAW) & "')")
            End Try
        End Sub
```

***Page 2***

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="iBase.CommonScript" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<script runat="server">   
    '** STANDARD Declarations **
    Private ps As iBase.PageScript
    Const PageTitle As String = "Upload File"
    '** End of STANDARD Declarations **

    Dim file As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload

    Private Shared Login As iBase.Application.LoginScript
    Protected Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        '** STANDARD Initialisations **
        ps = New iBase.PageScript(Page)
        '** End of STANDARD Initialisations **
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        '** STANDARD Initialisations **
        Me.Header.Title = Application("AppTitle") & " - " & PageTitle
        ps.PageLoad()

        ps.ValidateForm = True
        '** End of STANDARD Initialisations ** 

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()

        Dim validator As New Validator(ps)
        file = FileFunctions.NewUploadControl("uploadfile", "", PlaceHolder1)
        If IsPostBack = False Then
            FileFunctions.ResetUploadControl(file)
        End If
        With file
            .EnableViewState = False
            .Attributes("onuploadcompleted") = "UploadDone"
        End With
        'Validator.Add(file, Component.Validator.ValidateType.Required, "")
    End Sub
    
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=PageScript.VirtualDir%>App_Files/_JavaScript/UIForm.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function UploadDone(filepath, filename) {
        UIForm_UploadDone(filepath, filename)             
        window.close()
    }
</script>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="15">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"
        EnablePageMethods="false">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="divForm" style="padding-top: 13px">
                Click <b>Browse</b> to select the file.
                <table width="100%" border="0" style="table-layout: fixed">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col align="left" width="90">
                        <tr height="6">
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td><span class="Label"><%= PageScript.Translate("Upload File")%></span>:&nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                <i style="font-size:9pt"><%=PageScript.Translate("File Size Allowed")%> : <b><%=Application("MaxFileSizeMB")%>MB max.</b></td>                            
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="6">
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                        
                        </col>
                    </colgroup>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Page 3***

```
var UIForm_UploadFileID

function UIForm_UploadFile(elID) {
    UIForm_UploadFileID = elID
    var dialogattr = "dialogTop:0px;dialogLeft:0px;dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:195px;scroll:yes;status:no;"
    formname = AppFolder + "App_Files/_Components/UploadFile.aspx"
    winform = window.showModalDialog(formname, window, dialogattr, elID);           
}

function UIForm_UploadDone(filepath, filename) { 
    if ((filepath != "") && (filename != "")) {
        UIForm_SetUploadFile(UIForm_UploadFileID, filepath, filename)        
    }
}

function UIForm_SetUploadFile(elID, filepath, filename) {
   
    if (elID) {
        elID.options[elID.options.length] = new Option(filename, filepath)
        elID.options[elID.options.length - 1].selected = true
    }   

}
```

***Page 4***

```
<%Sub DrawFileObject(byval FieldName, byval FieldDesc, byval FieldValue, byval Folder)%>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="<%=Application("VirtualDir")%>App_Files/_JavaScript/UIForm.js"></script><%'change 21%>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tr><td style="border:none">
            <select style="width:100%" name="<%=FieldName%>" id="<%=FieldName%>" validate="0" title="<%=GetTabName()%><%=BiTranslate(FieldDesc)%>">
                <option value></option>
                <%if FieldValue<>"" then%>
                <option value="<%=FieldValue%>" selected><%=GetFileName(FieldValue)%></option>
                <%end if%>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="border:none" width="150" align="center">
            <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="padding-left:5px" onclick="ViewFile(this.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0].value)"><%=Translate("View")%></a>
            |<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="padding-left:5px" onclick="UploadFile(this.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].children[0])"><%=Translate("Browse")%>...</a>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
<%end sub%>
```

I found out that when Browse File link is clicked, it will passed the HTMLElement object to another page which will open a popup for user to upload the file. In another page, the HTMLElement object is stored in a global variable to be used when the upload has been completed. However, when the upload is done, the global variable become undefined instead of storing the HTMLElement object. I also tried to pass the HTMLElement object as an URL but still failed.

Comment: Why is code being used to create and inject the up-load control? Just place the control in the page markup and that will as general rule fix and cause events for that control to trigger (in your case the uploadedComplete). And no need to post boatloads of code here. Code for the file type can be shortened to a few lines of code by using minemapping feature. Create a blank page, and ONLY include the code for the upload control, and see if that works. Then progressive add more code and parts to that page until it fails. Without a simple reproducible code example here we we really can't help much